# How to clone a linked list with a head/tail implementation?

Tags: c, linked-list

I have a linked list with the following struct implementation:

```
struct _node {
    int item;
    struct _node *next;
}

struct _list {
    struct _node *head;
    struct _node *tail;
    int size;
}
```

I would like to write a function that clones the linked list and return a new list without modifying the original. I know how to do this using the _node implementation but I don't know how to do it using the _list implementation.

```
struct _node *cloneList (struct _node *head) {
    if (head == NULL) return NULL;

    struct _node *result = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
    result->item = head->item;
    result->next = cloneList(head->next);
    return result;
}
```

Here is what I have done:

```
struct _list *cloneList (struct _list *list) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    struct _list *result = malloc(sizeof(struct _list));
    result->size = list->size;
    result->head = list->head;
    result->tail = list->tail;
    return result;
}
```

but this is a buggy implementation because it doesn't actually clone the list because the pointers to head and tail are still the same.

Comment: Be aware that your function is not tail recursive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must combine your old function that does the actual cloning of the list elements with your new function that only clones the "management" part of the list.

To do this could modify your previous version a bit:

```
struct _node *cloneList (struct _list *list, struct _node *head) {
  if (head == NULL) return NULL;

  struct _node *result = malloc(sizeof(struct _node));
  result->item = head->item;
  if (head->next)
    result->next = cloneList(list, head->next);
  else
    list->tail = result;
  return result;
}
```

Then call it from within a new function

```
struct _list *cloneFullList (struct _list *list) {
    if (list == NULL) return NULL;

    struct _list *result = malloc(sizeof(struct _list));
    result->size = list->size;
    if (list->head != NULL) {
      result->head = cloneList(result, list->head);
      // tail will be set in cloneList as well.
    }
    else {
      result->head = result->tail = NULL;
    }
    return result;
}
```